# cuda copy array from global memory to shared memory

Tags: cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I'm trying to copy 2 arrays from global memory to shared memory:

- The global array's type is `double` and they have 32 elements each.
- The grid is 1D and the blocks are 1D.
- The grid dimension is 10000 and `NumberThreadPerBlock` is 32

Code:

```
__global__ void kernel_0(double px[], double py[], int N)
{
    int ii,
        jj,tid;
    tid=blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    __shared__ double s_px[256];
    __shared__ double s_py[256];
    __shared__ double s[256];

    s_px[threadIdx.x]=px[tid];
    s_py[threadIdx.x]=py[tid];
    s[threadIdx.x]=py[tid];
    __syncthreads();
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    double *px, *py , *x, *y, PI, step, *d_x, *d_y,*d_px, *d_py,sharedMemSize;
    int N, Nx, ii;
    PI = 4*atan(1.0);
    Nx = 10000; 
    N = 32; 
    
    px = (double *) malloc(N*sizeof(double));
    py = (double *) malloc(N*sizeof(double));

    // lookup table: sin // from 0 to PI 
    step = 1.0 / (N-1);
    for (ii = 0; ii < N; ii++){ 
        px[ii] = ii*step*PI;
        py[ii] = sin(px[ii]);
    }   

    cudaMalloc( (void **) &d_px, N*sizeof(double) );
    cudaMalloc( (void **) &d_py, N*sizeof(double) );        

    cudaMemcpy( d_px, px, N*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
    cudaMemcpy( d_py, py, N*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
        
    dim3 dimGrid(Nx);
    dim3 dimBlock(N,1,1);
    kernel_0<<< dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(px, py, N);
}
```

It compiles but `cuda-memmcheck` shows me many errors:

```
========= Invalid __global__ read of size 8
=========     at 0x00000058 in kernel_0
=========     by thread (31,0,0) in block (6,0,0)
=========     Address 0x11e0db38 is out of bounds
=========
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 96 errors
```

Can you help me?

Comment: This kernel will not run as shown here. Please post the actual kernel you are using.

Comment: Please also include your allocation of the global arrays and the kernel invocation.  Probably best if you post a complete, simple, compilable example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I would bet that `tid` is being used in one of the reads of either `px` or `py`, but you would have to show your *actual* code to confirm it.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, the memory allocated to the device pointers (`px`, `py`) is `32*sizeof(double)` big, however the number of blocks you have is 10000.

Device memory is global and all blocks share it, only the shared memory is defined for each block.
Therefore for `blockId.x >= 1`, you should get an invalid memory access.

Moreover, in the kernel launch, it should be `d_px`, `d_py`.